# Connecting MATLAB GUI to .m file

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have a m file, which chops the signal and applies filter according to the cut off frequency(Fc).

M file:

```html
classdef Container < handle
    properties
     segments = struct('signal', {}, 'time', {},'ref',{}); %empty structure with correct fields
   end
    
    methods
          function this = addsignal(this, signal, time,fc)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%chopping of the signals%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            interval = diff(time);
            [~, locations] = findpeaks(interval,'THRESHOLD',0.7);
            edges = [0; locations; numel(signal)+1];
            newsegments = struct('signal', cell(numel(edges)-1, 1), 'time', cell(numel(edges)-1, 1)); 
             %this loop works for no peaks, 1 peak and more than one peak (because of the 0 and numel+1)
             for edgeidx = 1 : numel(edges) - 1
                newsegments(edgeidx).signal = signal(edges(edgeidx)+1 : edges(edgeidx+1)-1);
                newsegments(edgeidx).time =   time(edges(edgeidx)+1 : edges(edgeidx+1)-1);
             end


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%filtering%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
             f = ltiFilter.PT1(); % another class which has filters
             f.Ts = mean(diff(time));
             f.fc = fc; % i want to set this value from the slider%%%%%
             f.zeroPhaseShift = 1;
             for i = 1:length(newsegments)
                 newsegments(i).ref = f.eval(newsegments(i).signal,newsegments(i).signal(1)); % application of the filter.
                 newsegments(i).ref = newsegments(i).ref';
             end
             
            this.segments = [this.segments; newsegments];
          end
     end  
end
```

I created a GUI which has a plot and a slider(for cut off frequcy) which is shown in code as `f.fc` 
[image]

when i created the GUI, Matlab automatically created a Code for me(i must say, I din't understand that much)

GUI code:

```html
function varargout = GUI(varargin)
% GUI MATLAB code for GUI.fig
%      GUI, by itself, creates a new GUI or raises the existing
%      singleton*.
%
%      H = GUI returns the handle to a new GUI or the handle to
%      the existing singleton*.
%
%      GUI('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
%      function named CALLBACK in GUI.M with the given input arguments.
%
%      GUI('Property','Value',...) creates a new GUI or raises the
%      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
%      applied to the GUI before GUI_OpeningFcn gets called.  An
%      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
%      stop.  All inputs are passed to GUI_OpeningFcn via varargin.
%
%      *See GUI Options on GUIDE's Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one
%      instance to run (singleton)".
%
% See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

% Edit the above text to modify the response to help GUI

% Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 15-Jul-2016 09:37:09

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @GUI_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @GUI_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before GUI is made visible.
function GUI_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to GUI (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for GUI
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% UIWAIT makes GUI wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);


% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = GUI_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;


% --- Executes on slider movement.
function slider1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to slider1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'Value') returns position of slider
%        get(hObject,'Min') and get(hObject,'Max') to determine range of slider


% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function slider1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to slider1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: slider controls usually have a light gray background.
if isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor',[.9 .9 .9]);
end


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton3.
function pushbutton3_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton3 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
```

What i want to do is, i want to connect the GUI to my m script, when user sildes the slider . it should show the change in graph automatically and when he clicks on apply. the value of slider should be taken and should be available in my m file.

Any leads will be helpful.

Comment: Why is this marked 'C++'?

Comment: Sorry my bad, changed

Answer (score 0):

From code sample pasted, I'm assuming you are using MATLAB GUIDE. 
Let's assume name of slider control is "slider1".
Add a callback function for "slider" using GUIDE.
It will create a function "`function slider1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)`" in your code. 
Now, to get value selected from slider movement use "get" function with "hObject".
E.g. `SliderVal=get(hObject,'Value');`

Now if you want to know value of slider selection from other callbacks (such as Apply button)
use handles structure.
E.g.: `SliderVal=get(handles.slider1,'Value');`

Based on slider value, received you need to re-draw plot area. 
I hope this helps as clue you are expecting.

**Edit1:**
For followup comment, how to get data from other M-file:
This will be very tricky. Because, you need to know handle of slider control in other M-file.

One of the ways would be to get handle of figure first.

1. Set "HandleVisibility" property of GUI figure (via GUIDE) to "ON".
2. Call "`figures = get(0,'Children');`" from M-script to get list of all open figures. This will give vector of figure handles.
3. Scan through list of children and get handle of your application. (This can be done via using property `get(figures(1),'Name')`).
4. Let's assume you found that handle, repeat same process again to get children from it. `get(figHandle,'Children')`.
5. Scan through children and find slider control handle similar to approach as in step 3.
6. Now you have access to control and it's data.

I hope you understood it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. How do i get this value in my another m file, where i use this value to apply the filter